# APIInvocationError in Oracle Integration cloud

Tags: oracle, xslt, cloud, integration, paas

**Can APIInvocationError schema override in OIC ?**
Is it possible to override APIInvocation schema in integration using REST Adapter and publish orchestration?

Answer (score 0):

APIInvocationError is a custom error posted by the OIC iPaaS. So Oracle does not allow for overriding of its schema in any form.

There are a lot of issues with this particular error. For example it is very difficult to parse the error received in this schema for another OIC Integration properly as it is wrapped inside the ErrorDetails/Instance element as a String and does not come to the calling Integration as set by the invoked integration.